# MySql: Quickest way to append to current value in DB

Tags: php, mysql, database

I have a table with 32,000 entries.

Each entry has a JSON blob against it:

```
{
    "property1": "someValue",
    "property2": "AnotherValue"
}
```

I now need to **append** another property to this blob for every entrant so that we have:

```
{
    "property1": "someValue",
    "property2": "AnotherValue",
    "property3": "YetAnotherValue"
}
```

Because `someValue` and `AnotherValue` will be different for different entries I cannot just replace the old records with the new one. Instead (I'm guessing) I'm supposed to parse JSON, add `property3` and return it to DB for each of the 32,000 records.

What is the best way to achieve this? I have a MySql database which I interact with through PhpMyAdmin.

I tried writing a PHP script which will basically select and loop through every row, parse and append to my JSON blob and put it back up for every record. However after I run this in a browser it simply times out on me because it takes too long to execute (I suspect it's the wait time between pulling the blob and uploading it back up for every record).

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: what about `YetAnotherValue`? Is this different for every row too?

Comment: suppose you can get the value for `YetAnotherValue` by row in table form, then this could be performed by a single SQL statement with the help of REPLACE().

Comment: No for the purposes of adding it to DB it will be the same for each record. Later on it will change but when adding it can be the same for every record

Comment: The simplest way (not having to use command line php or to change the apache/php configuration file) is to parse maximum 1000 records at once (that is refresh the page 32 times) and have the script automatically find the continuation point of last run (the records that do not have "property3" in the json blob).

Comment: So, it would be nice to get a closure for this case. Did you use any of the suggested methods? If so, please mark one of them as accepted. If you came up with something else, please post a new answer and accept that answer of yours.

Answer (score 1):

I would question the need to save JSON into a MySQL DB directly. Let's say your table with the JSON blob is called `my_table` and it has an `id` field. I'd create another table, say, `my_json_properties`. There, I'd create three columns: `my_table_id`, `property_name` and `property_value`. Then just populate that table with the JSON properties, and adding new properties is trivial. Also remember to delete the blob column and of course to update your data access objects.

Note: use the InnoDB storage engine so you get to make the `my_json_properties.my_table_id` into a foreign key that references `my_table.id`. MySQL also automatically creates an index with the foreign key columns, so it's very effective to query the properties when you just know the id in the original table.

Comment: Hi @ZeroOne - wouldn't I need a new row for each of the 32,000 records in the db? The JSON blob should be able to be unique per each record. If I do have it as a unique entry, then I will end up with two tables - one containing all my current data with 32,000 entries and another table with 32000 entries just for the corresponding JSON blobs. Will this really speed things up?

Comment: You'd end up with the original table of 32000 entries and another with 3x32000=96000 entries. You wouldn't store any JSON text in the database anymore, just key-value -pairs. When you require the data that used to be in the JSON blob, you just query all rows from the other table that match the id of your original table, then generate the JSON piece on the fly. 32000 is not that much, I don't think performance would be an issue.

Comment: Also, I don't know about the characteristics of your data, but if you ever need to query all items where, say, `property1` has a given value, then with you current schema it's very, very inefficient, whereas my schema would make it much more efficient.

Answer (score 1):

You could use an UPDATE statement to add this new property to your json blob, if the json is regular, i.e. there's no blank after the last property and the } has got a fixed position in the next line. Building on your example and assuming \n as end of line you could do it like that:

```
UPDATE example
SET json = REPLACE(
               json, 
               '"\n}', 
               '",\n    "property3": "some value"\n}');
```

Demo(http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/db972/1)

A more robust approach would be by the suggestions of Marcus Adams:

```
UPDATE example
SET json = 
    CONCAT(
        TRIM(
            TRAILING FROM TRIM(
                TRAILING '\n' FROM TRIM(
                    TRAILING FROM SUBSTRING_INDEX(json, '}', 1)
                )
            )
        ),
        ',\n    "property3": "some value"\n}'
    );
```

This will work independently of trailing spaces after the last property and leading spaces before the `}`, but it's still relying on the `\n` as end of line.

**Note:**

Such statements are usually much faster than row by row updating with a script.

Comment: `REPLACE()` is probably a good enough solution, but it might be better to use a function that doesn't have to search through the entire string. Perhaps `SUBSTR()` + `CHAR_LENGTH()` + `CONCAT()` or `TRIM(TRAILING...)` + `CONCAT()`.

Comment: @MarcusAdams I think you're right that my approach is not the fastest one. I assume this is a one time job. If it's not then I think storing of the json blob in a column isn't a good idea at all.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on use case.
If this is a one time task, it would be MUCH better to run your script from the shell and not from browser to avoid web server and browser timeouts.

```
php -f my_update_script.php
```

If you cannot run script from the shell for whatever reason you can try to fool the browser and web server as follows:

```
set_time_limit(3600*2); // two hours should be enougth?
// turn off output buffering
while (ob_end_flush());
ob_implicit_flush();

// Your mysql fetch..update loop here
// begin loop
echo 'Something useful every iteration to let them know your script is alive :)';
// end loop
```

However this approach may fail if there is caching reverse proxy in front of your web server.

MariaDb has native support for JSON format (since version 10), you may consider to switch to MariaDb.